# Given a positive integer N, how many ways can we write it as a sum of consecutive positive integers?(incorrect when convert for loop to while loop)

Tags: python-3.x

when I use the for loop, the function gives correct outputs, after I convert the for loop to while loop, the function gives incorrect outputs, is anyone know where is the problem and how to change the incorrect code to let it give correct outputs?

```
correct:

def consecutiveNumbersSum(N):
    ans = 0
    for start in range(1, N+1):
        target = N
        while target > 0:
            target -= start
            start += 1
        if target == 0: 
            ans += 1
    return ans
print(consecutiveNumbersSum(5))
print(consecutiveNumbersSum(9))

incorrect:

def consecutiveNumbersSum(N):
    ans= 0
    start= 1
    while start >= 1 and start <=N:        
        target = N
        start+=1
        while target > 0 :
            target-=start
            start+=1
        if target==0:
            ans+=1           
    return ans
print(consecutiveNumbersSum(5))
print(consecutiveNumbersSum(9))

expected:
2
3
actual:
2
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while start >= 1 and start <=N:
```

should be

```
while start >= 1 and start <= N+1:
```

And move

```
start += 1
```

to the end of your while loop. As it is, you're skipping the first number, basically.

Comment: but the function still gives the output 2,2

Comment: which while loop does 'start+=1' move to?